# iOS and live streaming mjpeg

Tags: ios, video-streaming

can you help me how can I stream my video to iOS app. I used UIWebView but video isnt chaning. Is there any solution. For example this stream. `http://80.32.204.149:8080/mjpg/video.mjpg`

Thank you for replies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do MJPG streaming on iOS is by using `UIImageView` and `NSURLConnection`. Use `NSURLConnection` to build the connection to your target URL and implement the delegate following methods:

`- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data` --> fill up a buffer with the data that you receive here (the buffer should be of type `NSData` and can be either an instance variable or a property)

`- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response` and convert the data from your buffer there into a `UIImage` using `[UIImage imageWithData:buffer]`. This `UIImage` can then be set on your `UIImageView`.

Comment: Okey I tried something but recievedData is null always. Can you help me? http://pastebin.com/agD0GHvH

Comment: hmm,... that actually looks ok. maybe it's because you're not refering to the instance variable with `self`. try using `self.receivedData` instead of only `receivedData`.